# How many times does the for-loop run?

Tags: analysis, pseudocode

How many times does the for-loop run?

```
 done <- false 
 n <- 0   
 while (n < a-1) and (done = false) 
   done <- true
   for m <- a downto n
      if list[m] < list[m - 1] then 
        tmp <- list[m] 
        list[m] <- list[m-1] 
        list[m - 1] <- tmp
        done <- false 
 n <- n + 1 
return list
```

In the worst case, is the answer (n ^ 2 + n) / 2 correct?. Does the while-loop run n+1 times?

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: @YuHao: looks pseudocode to me.

Comment: `n` is a bound variable, so the answer cannot contain it. the free variable is `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If downto includes the value of n, then:

- It will run for ((a+1)+a+(a-1)+(a-2)+...+1) times in the worst case. This equals ((a+1)*(a+2))/2.

If downto does not include the value of n, then:

- It will run for (a+(a-1)+(a-2)+...+1) times in the worst case. This equals (a*(a+1))/2.

In both cases, the while loop will run a times.

Comment: Will the inside of the inner for-loop also run ((a+1)*(a+2))/2 times?